# image not uploading in proper size on aws s3 server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, loopback

aws s3 bucket image not upload on actual size when i upload image on aws s3 bucket image size showing only 6 Byte that is not actual size of image.

why image is not uploading with actual size. i don't understand what is the issues.

**interst.js file**

```
    Interests.InterestIconUpload = async function (id , req, cb) {
        var Uploads = Interests.app.models.Uploads;
        let bucket = Interests.app.get('bucket');
        const path = `${bucket.interestIcon}`
        //const response = await Uploads.getFileFromRequest(req);
        const { fileName } = await Uploads.uploadFileToS3(path, req.body);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          Interests.updateAll({ "id": id }, { image: fileName }, function (err, update) {
            if (err) {
              reject(err);
            } else {
              Interests.findById(id, function (err, res) {
                if (err) {
                  reject(err);
                } else {
                  if (res && res.image) {

                    res.image = `https://${bucket.name}.s3.amazonaws.com/${bucket.uploads}/${bucket.interestIcon}/${id}/${res.image}`;
                  }
                  resolve(res);
                }
              })
            }
          })
        });
      }
```

this is **upload.js file**

```
Uploads.uploadFileToS3 = (path, file, options = {}) => {
           var app = Uploads.app;
        let bucket  = app.get('bucket');
        const fileName = file.name
        const extension = extname(file.path);
        let filePath = `${path}/medium_${fileName}`;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          return s3.upload({
            Bucket: bucket.name,
            ACL: 'public-read',
            Key: filePath,
            Body: 'buffer',
          }, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
              reject(err);
            }  else {
              console.log("result", result)
              resolve(result, {fileName: `${fileName}${extension}`});
            }
          });
        });
      };
```

this is aws s3 uploaded image [image]

Comment: I just want to point out that you are uploading a string (`'buffer'`) instead of your binary object. Try opening the file you uploaded and you might see that the content is `buffer`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code above.

a/ the promise should not return the result of S3 upload result.
b/ as Ionezer commented : the content you are uploading is the string 'buffer' (6 bytes) instead of your image. I am not sure where the bit and bytes come from in your code, maybe `req.body` ?

Try

```
Uploads.uploadFileToS3 = (path, file, options = {}) => {
           var app = Uploads.app;
        let bucket  = app.get('bucket');
        const fileName = file.name
        const extension = extname(file.path);
        let filePath = `${path}/medium_${fileName}`;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          s3.upload({
            Bucket: bucket.name,
            ACL: 'public-read',
            Key: filePath,
            Body: /** TO BE REPLACED WITH THE BYTES BUFFER OF YOUR CONTENT */,
          }, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
              reject(err);
            }  else {
              console.log("result", result)
              resolve(result, {fileName: `${fileName}${extension}`});
            }
          });
        });
      };
```